# tap for more information or stop the app

Tags: android, multithreading, service, notifications, intentservice

i create service and custom notification any thing work fine but android said
app is running on notification
tap for more information or to stop the app.
how can i fix this.

my custom BroadcastReceiver

```
public class ServiceBootCompleteReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent service = new Intent(context, ServiceNotification.class);
    context.startService(service);

  }
```

DO i need Unregister this Receiver?

my custom nitification class

```
    public class CustomNotification extends Notification {
      public void notifiaction(String txt) {
        ThreadSms thread = new Thread();
        threadSms.start();
;
        if (ThreadSms.newMessage) {
          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(GlobalController.currentActivity, ActivityMain.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GlobalController.context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
          Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
          RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(GlobalController.context.getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_toast);
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text, txt);
          NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(GlobalController.context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_icon)
            .setContent(remoteViews)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri).setAutoCancel(false)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(GlobalController.context.getResources(), R.drawable.modem))
            .setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 152, 0))
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
          GlobalController.notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

        }
      }
    }
```

my custom service

```
public class ServiceNotification extends IntentService {

  public ServiceNotification() {
    super("notify");
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      GlobalController.timerTaskService = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          CustomNotification customNotification = new CustomNotification();
          customNotification.notifiaction(message);
          startForeground(1, customNotification);
        }
      };

      GlobalController.timerService.scheduleAtFixedRate(GlobalController.timerTaskService, 0, 5000);

    return Service.START_STICKY;
  }

  public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
      this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000, restartServicePI);

  }
```

manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <application
        android:name=".app.GlobalController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activity.ActivityLogin">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.ActivitySplashScreen"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.ActivityMain"/>
        <activity android:name=".activity.ActivityAdvanceSetting"/>
        <receiver
            android:name=".services.ServiceBootCompleteReciver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service
            android:name=".services.ServiceNotification"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"/>
    </application>
```

Comment: cant any one help me ?

Comment: I think that the problem is here:
startForeground(1, customNotification);
because customNotification has no icon nor intent set.

Comment: +1 to @royas. My custom notification gets replaced by the "Tap for more information . . . " just because I forgot to `setSmallIcon(int icon)`

Answer (score 14):

On Android 10, you **MUST call setSmallIcon** on your notification, otherwise the notification will be ignored.  (The same is not true on Android 11, where it works regardless of whether you set the small icon.)  If you fail to set the small icon, instead of your notification you will see a canned Android notification instead of your own:

[image]

This code with `setSmallIcon` works:

```
                new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.myicon))
                        .setLargeIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.myicon))
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_CALL)
                        .setExtras(extras)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, "Accept", piAcceptIntent)
                        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);
```

This code without `setSmallIcon` causes the problem:

```
                new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
                        .setLargeIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.myicon))
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_CALL)
                        .setExtras(extras)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_call, "Accept", piAcceptIntent)
                        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true);
```

In the comments above, @royas and @Flamychandayo found this solution.  I am adding this as an answer to help make the solution more clear to those who come across this question.

Comment: I was banging my head against the wall until I found this. I'm trying to create the `Notification` manually (without `Notification.Builder`) and so I found that I _must_ set the `icon` field otherwise the same thing occurs

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for!